# How do I get a SwiftUI Text view to lay out my text top-left aligned?

Tags: swiftui, text-alignment

I figured out how to make a text view's contents scroll by enclosing it in a ScrollView.

However, when there is not enough content to fill a line, it ignores my request to use leading alignment and center-aligns it both horizontally and vertically.

```
ScrollView() {
    Text(userSettings.wordList)
        .lineLimit(nil)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        .padding(.all, 2)
        .frame(minWidth: geometry.size.width - 30, minHeight: 200)
        .border(.blue)
}
.contentMargins(2, for: .scrollContent)
.border(.gray)
```

That code (with a blue border around the `Text` view, so you can see how it lands inside the `ScrollView`) looks like this with 2 words in the `Text` view:

[image]

I want the text to be left (er, leading) aligned horizontally, and top-aligned vertically. How do I do that?

Comment: What happens if you add an `alignment` to your `frame`?

Comment: @jnpdx, that does it. Thanks! Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, your `frame` has no alignment and is defaulting to `center`. You can fix this by adding an explicit alignment:

```
.frame(minWidth: geometry.size.width - 30, minHeight: 200, alignment: .topLeading)
```

Comment: Thanks. This confusing to me. What does an alignment mean in the context of a frame? The enclosing box that the text gets drawn into is its frame.

Comment: Yes, that `frame` is a container -- it has to know how to lay out its contents. Although it looks like a modifier, it might be more helpful to think of it like this: `Frame { Text() }` where the contents are arbitrary and need layout information.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I can make UIKIt sit up and dance. With SwiftUI, everything I know is wrong.